# How do I fix Deprecations warning messages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, deprecated

I used some code from a project that used xib.  I use storyboards.  I'm new to coding.  The code ran fine, but I have 17 Deprecations warnings for UITextAlignment (Center and Left), UILineBreakModeWordWrap, presentModalViewController:animated, dismissModalViewControllerAnimated, and minimumFontSize. That they are deprecated in iOS 6.0. I thought I had added the right files to avoid these (e.g., ReaderViewController, ThumbsViewController, ReaderMain, ReaderMainPagebar, etc) from the xib-based example, and compiled them.  Any clues on how I can fix these?  Is this serious?

```
self.imageRoll = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fPath];
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageRoll];
```

Also, in the code above, I keep getting a message 'incompatible pointer types sending "UIImage *" to parameter of type "NSString *"' for this variable "imageRoll".  Suggestions to deal with this?  The lines are in different methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fix deprecated warnings by replacing your use of the deprecated symbol with its proper replacement. But make sure that the new symbol will work with all versions of iOS you need to support.

Example - `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` was deprecated and replaced with `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. The good news in this case is that you can safely replace `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` with `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. Both have the same enum value so the change will work with all versions of iOS.

`presentModalViewController:animated` was deprecated and replaced with `presentViewController:animated:completion:` in iOS 5.0. As long as you are not trying to support iOS 4.3, replace your use of `presentModalViewController:animated` with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Look in the reference docs for each deprecated symbol. The documentation almost always tells you the replacement. Again, make sure the replacement method is available all the way back to whatever Deployment Target you are using.

Your issue with the two lines of code you posted is simple. `self.imageRoll` is a property defined as a `UIImage` pointer. The `UIImage imageNamed:` method expects an `NSString` specifying a filename. Since you already have an image from the 1st line, the 2nd line should simply be:

```
UIImage *anImage = self.imageRoll;
```

Comment: Thank you for both issues.  I thought that was the case for the deprecated, but waned to make sure before I made all these changes.

Comment: I fixed them, except of dissModal and presentModal.  I don't undersand the ref docs.

Comment: The first line is what I'm trying to place.  The others are what I have tried.

 [self presentModalViewController:thumbsViewController animated:NO];
    [self presentViewController:animated:NO completion:thumbsViewController];
    [self presentViewController:thumbsViewController animated:NO];
    [self presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:NO completion:thumbsViewController];
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:NO completion:thumbsViewController];

Comment: here is the dismissmodal.- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController {
 Original --   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 I tried --   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:(void (^)(void))];

I don't understand the completion part of either the diss or present. I keep getting error messages of undefined variables or misuse of BOOL.

Comment: Simply pass `nil` to the `completion:` parameter unless you actually want to provide a completion block.